# How to programmatically configure custom host in jetty server (8.1.8.v20121106) with SslSelectChannelConnector?

Tags: java, ssl, https, jetty, keytool

I want to access a servlet with https connection as the following address "https://ip-address:port/servletPath" . For this I am using SslSelectChannelConnector with jetty server (version 8.1.8.v20121106).

1. I generated self signed certificate using keytool with the following information,

   ```
       CN=localhost, OU=<myorg>, O=<myorg>, L=Trivandrum, ST=Kerala, C=IN
   ```
2. I have configured the jetty server - SslSelectChannelConnector as follows,

   ```
       SslContextFactory sslFactory = new SslContextFactory();
       sslFactory.setKeyStorePath("<path of the generated key store by keytool>");
       sslFactory.setKeyStorePassword("mypassword");
       sslFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("mypassword");

       sslFactory.setTrustStore("<path of the signed trust store by keytool>");
       sslFactory.setTrustStorePassword("mypassword");

       SslSelectChannelConnector sslSelectConnector = new SslSelectChannelConnector(sslFactory);
       sslSelectConnector.setPort(5443);
   ```
3. Registered servlet for the path => servletPath as follows,

   ```
    ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(httpServlet);

    this.servletContextHandler.addServlet(holder, servletPath);
   ```
4. When i start the server, i am getting the console as follows,

   INFO [main] (AbstractConnector.java:338) - Started SslSelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:5443
       DEBUG [main] (AbstractLifeCycle.java:172) - STARTED SslSelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:5443
5. when I try to access with the following address,
   //localhost:5433/servletPath => servlet is getting invoked - executed successfully.
6. In my case I need to access like => //192.168.27.29:5433/servletPath.

I tried to set the host as   "sslSelectConnector.setHost("192.168.27.29");  ". When I start the server i got the console as follows

```
INFO [main] (AbstractConnector.java:338) - Started SslSelectChannelConnector@192.168.27.29:5443
DEBUG [main] (AbstractLifeCycle.java:172) - STARTED SslSelectChannelConnector@192.168.27.29:5443
```

7. But when I try to access with the following address, //192.168.27.29:5433/servletPath => exection failed with the exception,

[Error Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbg7G.png)

So, how to bind the custom port with jetty server, any suggestions.

Comment: [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) Consider upgrading to the Jetty 9 series soon.  Also note, if you are using SSL, you are *highly encouraged* to upgrade both Jetty and your JVM to stay current with the rapidly changing landscape of SSL/TLS on the general internet.